# Ingeniería inversa en un videojuego, como sustituyo un dominio por una IP personal?

Tags: ingeniería-inversa

Estoy aplicando ingeniería inversa en un juego, cuyo .exe contiene la dirección "http://ejemplo.com" y la quiero sustituir por una IP específica para crear yo un servidor. Es un proyecto experimental, ya logré editar el .exe en un editor HEX y substituir la http por la IP, pero me sigue conectando a ejemplo.com

Sé que el asunto está en el .exe, ya que otra compañía creó un servidor del mismo juego y solo te dan el link de descarga del .exe como "Parche" para conectarte a su servidor

Tienen alguna idea de qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: eso quiere decir que tu pregunta es muy amplia. Y en efecto lo es. Modificar datos de un binario no siempre es suficiente para que algo funcione. Como sabes que esa posición de memoria es la que tenes que modificar? Ingenieria reversa, es descompilar el exe, hacer los cambios, y volverlo a compilar. Vos solo estas modificando el exe.

Comment: ahhh! ya entiendo entendo,  dale, mira también descompilé el exe y me salio un archivo, no intenté eso, creí que modificando la url directo en el notepad me iba a funcionar, de verdad muchas gracias. Ojala me hubiesen comentado esto desde un inicio todo habria sido mas simple, llevo un mes haciendo corajes con esos gringos engreidos que me cierran todo lo que pregunto sin explicarme nada... es duro por que soy nuevo y quiero aprender

Comment: es que preguntar estas cosas, no esta para nada bien visto. y menos en el sitio ingles.

Comment: Entiendo, le tienen como prejuicio u odio a los procesos inversos verdad? A mi parecer son muy puritanos allá

Comment: no. es que te estas robando el trabajo de otro. no tiene nada que ver con ser puristas.

Comment: No demos por hecho cosas, solo estoy tratando de observar como funciona desde una perspectiva inversa... también podría ser un proyecto opensource que compilé, y que deseo reversar para aprender algo nuevo

 A demas, es importante que recordemos ese viejo concepto de la vieja escuela geek "Copiar no es robar" encima esa empresa también robó ... larga historia...

Comment: @gbianchi hermano, más directo, imposible. Brother "Academia Gamer", aquí te djo un enlace: https://unity3d.college/ para que aprendas sobre desarrollo de videojuegos utilizando Unity3D. Saludos

Comment: si cuando haces ingenieria reversa. y si fuera un proyecto open source, no necesitarias hacerlo. si quieres podemos seguir esta conversacion en el [chat]

Comment: gracias fredy y si, ya entro al chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si estás trabajando en Windows, podés usar el archivo HOSTS para redireccionar todas las peticiones a **ejemplo.com** hacia tu IP local.

Abrí este archivo:

C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

Y agregá la línea:

```
127.0.0.1   ejemplo.com
```

Los cambios son inmediatos, pero algunos programas guardan una caché interna de las DNS que van resolviendo, así que si no funciona, reiniciá la máquina.

Tené en cuenta que esto aplica para todo el sistema operativo, y no vas a poder acceder a **ejemplo.com** de ninguna forma mientras esa línea exista en tu archivo HOSTS.

Comment: Te agradezco demasiado!

Comment: Solo agregar que también es posible en Linux modificando el archivo /etc/hosts de la misma manera